# Add multiple figures from a single pdf page to a List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfpages

I have inserted a pdf document using `\includepdf`. The document has several figures to a page that I want added to a List of Figures. Is there any way to do `addtolist={}` several times for the same instance of `\includepdf`? Any other solutions?

Comment: Sure you can use several `\addcontentsline` comments but are you sure it is the best way since the figures on your pdf file have probably already a number, a name which is not consistent with your numbering and so on. In order for us to help you further with your problem, can you post a picture of the pdf you are including and a compilable TeX code of what you are doing for now? Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered in a previous post (at the end of the post).

[pdfpages, addtolist and list of tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56093/pdfpages-addtolist-and-list-of-tables)